# Using non-constant properties or fields in key for @CacheEvict

Tags: java, spring, spring-cache

Is it possible to use the non constant fields or properties of current class in key of the `@CacheEvict` annotation? For example:

```
public class Feature {

    private int id;

    @Autowired
    private FeaturesClient featuresClient;

    @CacheEvict(value = CacheConfiguration.FEATURES, key = 
               "T(java.lang.String).valueOf(#userId).concat(T(java.lang.String)" +
               ".valueOf( **#id** ))")
    public boolean isFeatureAvailable(long userId) {
        return featuresClient.isFeatureAvailable(userId, id);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

```
@CacheEvict(key = "#userId + #root.target.id")
```

[Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/annotation/CacheEvict.html#key--):

> `#root.method`, `#root.target`, and `#root.caches` for references to the method, target object, and affected cache(s) respectively.